# How to Reference .Net Core Library in a .Net Core Console Application

Tags: macos, visual-studio, .net-core

I am following this [code example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/program-structure)

I am on Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac. I created a .Net Core - Class Library project and compiled to create the assembly file `P1-ProgramStructure.dll`.

I created another solution with `program2.cs` code. Please see the code below.
I renamed the `.dll` to `acme.dll` and copied the file into its directory.

Class library - .Net Core Project

**Program1.cs**

```
using System;
namespace Acme.Collections
{
    public class Stack
    {
        Entry top;
        public void Push(object data) 
        {
            top = new Entry(top, data);
        }

        public object Pop() 
        {
            if (top == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
            object result = top.data;
            top = top.next;
            return result;
        }

        class Entry
        {
            public Entry next;
            public object data;
            public Entry(Entry next, object data)
            {
                this.next = next;
                this.data = data;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

.Net Core Console App

**Program2.cs**

```
using System;
using Acme.Collections;
class Example
{
    static void Main() 
    {
        Stack s = new Stack();
        s.Push(1);
        s.Push(10);
        s.Push(100);
        Console.WriteLine(s.Pop());
        Console.WriteLine(s.Pop());
        Console.WriteLine(s.Pop());
    }
}
```

When I run the project, I get the error:

```
$ dotnet run
```

> Program.cs(15,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Acme' could    not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/csarami/VisStudioProjects/cSharp Projects/Project2-ProjectStructure/Project2-ProjectStructure/Project2-ProjectStructure.csproj]
>
> The build failed. Please fix the build errors and run again.

Comment: You must update the `.csproj` file associated with the project.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-add-reference and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-add-package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure both projects have the same target framework